# extract the usb name from 'blkid' output

Tags: python, label, extract, usb-drive, blkid

I want to extract the usb lable attached to my linux system. I have written some code in python, it works fine, but I want it to be less complicated. Any ideas ... Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import commands

 import os

 str1=commands.getoutput('sudo blkid')

 name=str1.splitlines()

 for x in range(len(name)):

 if '/dev/sd' in name[x]:

 print name[x]

 str2=name[x].split(" ")

 print str2

 for y in range(len(str2)):

 if 'LABEL' in str2[y]:

 print str2[y]

 str3=str2[y].split('=')

 print str3

 for z in range(len(str3)):

    if 'LABEL' in str3[z]:
            print str3[z+1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the options on `blkid` to simplify your task. In this case the `-s` to specify that you are only interested in the `LABEL`.

Then you can find the value of that by reverse searching for the `=` character, like so:

```
out = commands.getoutput('sudo blkid -s LABEL')
lines = out.splitlines()
for line in lines:
     if 'dev/sd' in line:
         index = line.rfind('=')
         param = line[index + 1:]
         print param
```